# How can I determine why JPA/eclipselink/J2EE is issuing a ROLLBACK to the DB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am chasing a problem where I see SQL statements run in my database log in a transaction, then see that transaction rolledback.

This happens on both Oracle and Postgres, but only on some installations. The application itself is a pretty standard J2EE application using JPA and Eclipselink.

I am not seeing any exceptions, nor is the code explicitly giving up and rolling back.

The best I have been able to do so far is find this log statement:

```
    [#|2011-09-26T11:30:56.052-0700|FINER|sun-appserver2.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/opt/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/myapp/myapp-ejb_jar/_myapp-ejbPU.transaction|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8888-2;ClassName=null;MethodName=null;_RequestID=e78196
09-bf2e-4026-8cbb-87fdd047c5eb;|begin unit of work flush|#]
```

It occurs at the exact same time as the ROLLBACK in the postgres log:

```
appuser @ dbname: 102012/7/67486 2011-09-26 18:30:56.052 UTC - LOG:  execute S_3: ROLLBACK
```

Note that the DB is on UTC while the application is on Pacific.

The relevant code is being called using a webservice with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)`

I am working with both logging levels and the debugger to see if I can find an exception being thrown and swallowed that might cause this.

How can I find out what code is causing the rollback?

Comment: Get the SQL that eclipselink is sending to the database and run that in database direct . Seems to me more of a database issue but I might be wrong. But eliminate that by trying this.

Comment: Shahzeb - Tried that. The database logs showed something calling ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable logging on finest with EclipseLink to debug the issue.
Any exception that occurred within EclipseLink will be logged.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Also ensure you are not throwing an error to cause your SessionBean to rollback.

Comment: Answer is a good general answer. Our specific problem was that there was a call to explicitly roll back in a `finally` clause which didn't write to our application logs.